# Проблема с вводом данных в EditText

Tags: java, android

В прокуте есть страница что получает с базы переменные, которые указывают какие View элементы должны быть созданы програмно, через код. На телефонах с версиями Android от 6.0, во все `EditText` получается написать данные, но на Android 5.1 не получается ввести данные.

Если быть точнее `EditText` выглядит будто задан `setEnabled(false)`, но элемент фокусится и также даёт написать данные в него, но не отображает их. Если при помощи кнопки назад вернуться на предыдущее окно, то элементы показываются в `EditText`.

Если надо что либо добавить в вопрос, пишите так как я просто не представляю как показать данный процесс

**На гифке попробовал показать проблему**

[image: проблема]

В данной функции я проверяю параметры в `inputParams` и смотря на флаги что указаны в них создаю элементы и добавляю в layout

```
private void buildForm(View parent, List<PaymentParams> inputParams) {
Collections.sort(inputParamses);
int edit_text_padding = (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.editTx_padding);
//Adding input forms
LinearLayout form = parent.findViewById(R.id.inputParamsContainer);
form.removeAllViewsInLayout();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, dpToPx(10), 0, dpToPx(10));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relparams.setMargins(0, dpToPx(10), 0, dpToPx(10));
for (PaymentParams params : inputParamses) {
    if (params.getParamType().equalsIgnoreCase("T") || params.getParamType().equalsIgnoreCase("N") || params.getParamType().equalsIgnoreCase("F") || params.getParamType().equalsIgnoreCase("I")) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        MyTextView textView = new MyTextView(getActivity());
        textView.setHint(params.getName());
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_12sp));
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDark));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        textView.setText(params.getName());
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final MaskEditText editText = new MaskEditText(getActivity());
        // set inputType of EditText
        if (params.getParamType().equals("T"))
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        if (params.getParamType().equals("N"))
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        if (params.getParamType().equals("F"))
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        if (params.getParamType().equals("I"))
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        if (params.getIsReadOnly().equals("Y"))
            editText.setEnabled(false);

        editText.setHint(params.getHint());
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDark));
        editText.setPadding(edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding);
        editText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_box));
        editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_14sp));
        editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDark));
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        if (params.getCode().equals("CARD_TRANSFER")) {
            cardNumber = editText;
            cardNumber.setMask("#### #### #### ####");
            cardNumber.setSelection(cardNumber.getText().length());
            cardNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                    final String text = s.toString().replace(" ", "");
                    if (text.length() == 16) {
                        // CHECK USER CARD ON DB
                    } else {
                        aboutUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

            aboutUser = new MyTextView(getActivity());
            aboutUser.setHint(params.getName());
            aboutUser.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            aboutUser.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_14sp));
            aboutUser.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey));
            aboutUser.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            aboutUser.setText("");
            linearLayout.addView(aboutUser);
            aboutUser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (params.getPaymentDetailCode().equals("CELL_PHONE") || params.getCode().equals("TELEPHONE")) {
            if (phoneNumber != null)
                linearLayout.removeView(phoneNumber);
            phoneNumber = editText;
            phoneNumber.setMaxLength(16);
            phoneNumber.setSelection(phoneNumber.getText().length());
            phoneNumber.setMask("###### ### ## ##");
            phoneNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_form_phone, 0, 0, 0);
            phoneNumber.setCompoundDrawablePadding(25);
        }
        if (params.getCode().equals("SUM")) {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            amountEdit = new MaskEditText(getActivity());
            if (params.getParamType().equals("T"))
                amountEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            if (params.getParamType().equals("N"))
                amountEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            if (params.getParamType().equals("F"))
                amountEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            if (params.getParamType().equals("I"))
                amountEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            if (params.getIsReadOnly().equals("Y"))
                amountEdit.setEnabled(false);

            amountEdit.setHint(params.getHint());
            amountEdit.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_box));
            amountEdit.setLayoutParams(relparams);
            amountEdit.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDark));
            amountEdit.setPadding(edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding, edit_text_padding);
            amountEdit.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_14sp));
            amountEdit.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDark));
            amountEdit.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            amountEdit.addTextChangedListener(onTextAmountChangedListener());
            amountEdit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_form_payment, 0, 0, 0);
            amountEdit.setCompoundDrawablePadding(((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.editTx_padding)));
            amountEdit.setTag(params.getCode());

            if (params.getDefValue().length() > 0 && !params.getDefValue().equals("0"))
                amountEdit.setText(params.getDefValue());
            relativeLayout.addView(amountEdit);
            linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
        } else {
            editText.setTag(params.getCode());
            if (params.getDefValue().length() > 0 && !params.getDefValue().equals("0"))
                editText.setText(params.getDefValue());
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
        }
        if (!params.getIsVisible().equals("Y")) linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        form.addView(linearLayout);
    } else if (params.getParamType().equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        spinner.setPadding(dpToPx(10), dpToPx(10), dpToPx(10), dpToPx(10));
        spinner.setTag(params.getCode());
        String empty_string;

        MobileDBHelper dbHelper = new MobileDBHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        refParamList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            refParamList = dbHelper.getRefParamList(params.getRefCode(), null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < refParamList.size(); i++) {
            CodeAndName codeAndName = new CodeAndName();
            codeAndName.setCode(refParamList.get(i).getCode());
            codeAndName.setName(refParamList.get(i).getName());
            spinnerList.add(codeAndName);
        }
        if (params.getRefCode().trim().length() == 0) {
            EmptyCodeAndNameAdapter codeAndNameAdapter = new EmptyCodeAndNameAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
            spinner.setAdapter(codeAndNameAdapter);
        } else {
            CodeAndNameAdapter adapter = new CodeAndNameAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        if (params.getCode().equals("SECTOR")) {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(sectorListener);
        } else {
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (((CodeAndName) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getCode().equals("empty")) {
                        TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
                        if (selectedText != null) {
                            selectedText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
        }
        if (!params.getIsVisible().equals("Y")) spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        form.addView(spinner);
        if (params.getIsReadOnly().equals("Y")) spinner.setEnabled(false);
        if (params.getDefValue().length() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < spinnerList.size(); index++) {
                if (spinnerList.get(index).getCode().equals(params.getDefValue())) {
                    spinner.setSelection(index);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Button submit = parent.findViewById(R.id.btnMakePayment);
submit.setAllCaps(false);
submit.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

PS. На других устройствах всё работает, проверил на версиях Android < 5.1 и начиная с 6.0 всё работает

Comment: нужно показать код, где вы программно делаете эти View.

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось, данная страница открывалась как фрагмент и вызывал следующим кодом

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .add(R.id.pay_company_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Получилось что, убрав `.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)` поле начало принимать данные.

то есть **Решением** стало

```
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .add(R.id.pay_company_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```